# How can I accept the nil value of a param while there is also a format defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, null, ruby-on-rails-5, string-formatting

This is the validation:

```
validates :phonenumber, allow_nil: true, format: { with: /\A\d{10}\z/, message: "not valid" }
```

When I do not put any value into phonenumber, it give me the error "phonenumber not valid". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What if you use `validates_format_of`? https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of

Comment: It's the same. I try your solution but it give me the same error.

Comment: what was it? Post a self-answer maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to use [allow_blank](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank) option:

```
validates :phonenumber,
          format: { with: /\A\d{10}\z/, message: "not valid" },
          allow_blank: true
```